# How to pass php variables to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php

The php code is:

```
$sql="SELECT `Variant`, COUNT(`Variant`) AS tsold,
      MONTHNAME(sold_date) AS mname
      FROM `vehicle_sold`
      GROUP BY MONTH(`sold_date`), `Variant` ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["Variant"],"---",$row["mname"],"---",$row["tsold"],"<br/>";     
}
```

I get the following required result and it shows me how many times each variant has been sold out in each month.

```
GLI A/T---January---1
GLI A/T---February---1
XLI M/T---February---1
GLI A/T---March---2
GLI M/T---March---2
Grande---March---1
XLI M/T---March---2
GLI A/T---April---2
GLI M/T---April---6
XLI M/T---April---3
GLI A/T---May---1
GLI M/T---May---4
Grande---May---1
GLI A/T---July---1
```

Now the problem is i want to shift this data to javascript

Comment: instead of *echo*ing out that line just push it into an array; then print it out in your JavaScript with something like `var jsArray = <?= json_encode($phpArray); ?>;`

Comment: A nice way of doing this would be to use AJAX, but I don't know if that's an option for you? Generally speaking you don't want to mix PHP and Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the result as a JS array, you could do this:

```
<?php
    $sql="...";
    /* Don't forget to execute the $sql query here */
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $myData[] = $row["Variant"]."---".$row["mname"]."---".$row["tsold"];     
    }
?>

<script>
    var myData = <?php echo json_encode($myData); ?>;
    alert( JSON.stringify(myData) );
</script>
```

Comment: would you pls tell me how to echo data() in php and how to extract and print in javascript???

Answer (score 2):

PHP code:

```
$sql="SELECT `Variant`, COUNT(`Variant`) AS tsold,
      MONTHNAME(sold_date) AS mname
      FROM `vehicle_sold`
      GROUP BY MONTH(`sold_date`), `Variant` ";
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;    
}
```

And in JavaScript:

```
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
//your JavaScript code with data
</script>
```

Comment: would you pls tell me  how to echo data() in php and how to extract and print in javascript???